# Pull request conflicts in BitBucket

Tags: request, bitbucket, conflict, pull

I have created a pull request in bitbucket and there are conflicts in those files. So, I cannot merge these files in the main repository. How can I resolve these conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Which Code Editor are you using?

Most have a spezial view oder mode for managing conflict.

Like VS Code + GitLense.

There you can see both versions side by side and edit your code and commit it agian.
Afterwarts you can try the merge again.